# Why algolia search of phrase in laravel app found all words of the phrase?

Tags: algolia, laravel-scout

Working with algolia in Laravel 10 app and using algolia/algoliasearch-client-php 3.4 and
algolia/scout-extended 3.0 packages I found that search method works different I expected when I enter
several space splitted words : it search for all words found in records.

I tested on algolia side and see that search works in the same way :

[image]

Can this issue can be configurable, say in  config/scout.php or on algolia side ?

Comment: im not familiar with laravel scout but from algolia side there is a [advancedSyntax](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/advancedSyntax/) param which u can enable. after that if you search the phrase surrounded by double quotes you should get exact matches